# String cannot be converted from Vertex

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Here is a short snippet of a larger project I am writing and I ran into a problem.
I'm calculating shortest distances in a weighted graph from one vertex to another.

```
Vertex A,B,C,D,F,G... = new Vertex("A"....); //Declarations for each vertex


//Loop thru each vertex and use it as a source.
for(int i=65;i<76;i++)
{
    computePaths(A);
    System.out.println(" Distance to " + K + " : " + K.minDistance);
    List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(K);
    System.out.println("Path: " + path);
}
```

and for some reason, whenever I try

```
computePaths(Character.toString( (char) i ));
```

instead it yells "String cannot be converted from Vertex"

Anyone know why?

Comment: is it because (char) i  returns A first. Which is also the name passed as a vertex var.

Comment: Also. What parameter types does computePaths() take in?

Comment: @DarkV1  computePaths( Vertex vertex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
computePaths(Character.toString( (char) i ));
```

tries to use the char 'A' as the Vertex named A. This does not work because computePaths takes a Vertex as a parameter, not a char. 
Thus you need some conditionals like.

```
switch (Character.toString( (char) i ))
{
   case A: computePaths(A);
   case B: computePaths(B);
   //So on
}
```

Comment: better yet, create a List<Vertex> and then index into it using `list.get(i)`.